# Web Bluetooth characteristic.writeValue break the connection automatically

Tags: android, google-chrome, web-bluetooth

I follows Google/chrome samples for Web Bluetooth. I have two writeValue operations.  One is within the requestDevice promise and it works perfectly.  Second one, I save the characteristic reference and writeValue when the action trigger.   The message is sent but connection broke automatically.  I am using Mac OSX 10.13.3 and chrome64 and modify Android BLE Peripheral Simulator (From google github)

The code segment ---

```
var bluetoothDevice;
var myCharacteristic;

navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
   ...
})
.then(device => {
  bluetoothDevice = device;
  ....
})
....
.then(characteristic =>{
    myCharacteristic = characteristic;
    let encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
    let sendMsg = encoder.encode("hello");

    /*
    It works... 
    */
    myCharacteristic.writeValue(sendMsg);
})
....

function onSendMessage() {
  if (!bluetoothDevice.gatt.connected) {
    log("device is disconnected")
    return
  } 

  if (!myCharacteristic){
    log("no characteristic defined")
    return
  }

  let encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
  let sendMsg = encoder.encode("hello");

  /* 
    message sent but auto disconnect the peripheral
   */ 
  myCharacteristic.writeValue(sendMsg);
}
```

Does anyone has same experience and any suggestion for keep connection persistence for writeValue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good to me. A similar code can be found as well at https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/link-loss.html

However I wonder which characteristic you're trying to write to. If that is not supported, the Android device might simply disconnect.

Check out https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs#TOC-Android and grab Android adb logs if that helps.